# Help Needed! Confusion with chain Rule. Someone clarify please.

Tags: differential-geometry, chain-rule

[image]

In the chain rule shouldn’t it be $\sigma_{\tilde u}$ for the second one? How do they get just $\sigma_u$ for both? Can someone clarify this please?[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems like a typo.

Comment: But in the next step he’s taking dot product to write the angle in terms of first fundamental form, for which it has to be $\sigma_u$ for both the curves. How is it so?

Comment: $\tilde{\gamma}$ is _independent_ of $u, v$ and only depends on $\tilde{u}, \tilde{v}$, so by the chain rule it _must_ be $\sigma_{\tilde{u}}, \sigma_{\tilde{v}}$. What you say about what the author does in the next part means nothing to me, I can't see what steps the author has taken.

Comment: I have added the next part now. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a typo. $\sigma(u,v)$ is the given parametrization of the surface. Its partial derivatives are $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$. You are going to plug in $u=u(t)$ or $u=\tilde u(t)$ to make your composed function. Perhaps it would be better to write $\sigma(g(t),h(t))$ and $\sigma(\tilde g(t),\tilde h(t))$ so you don't get confused. The multivariable chain rule is the most maligned creature on earth.